# Як правильно перекласти "упаковка" з російської

Tags: переклад, from-russian, словотворення, віддієслівні-іменники

Згідно з сучасними нормами правопису, віддієслівні іменники типу російських *съёмка*, *маркировка*, *стажировка* і т.д. перекладаються словами з суфіксом `-анн`, але тоді виникає значення процесу.

А як бути з результатами пакування, знімання, маркування?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мені подобається [ідея М. Гінзбурга](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2957/4) повернути в українську мову слово «**пако́вання**». Що було присутнє в словниках 1920-х–1930-х років ([«Російсько-український словник технічної термінології»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=4&highlight=on) І. Шелудька та Т. Садовського (1928), [«Російсько-український словник ділової мови»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=5&highlight=on) М. Дорошенка, М. Станиславського та В. Страшкевича (1930), [«Російсько-український академічний словник»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=1&highlight=on) А. Кримського та С. Єфремова (1924–1933)), але, наскільки я можу судити, відсутнє в сучасних словниках (наприклад, [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) від УМІФ НАНУ).

Однак допоки слово не внесене в авторитетні словники, використання його в офіційному мовленні може не завжди бути прийнятним. Тому наведу інші варіанти, що, хоч і не мають такої точності/загальності, але є словниковими.

## Коли мова йде про ємність/обгортку і її корисний вміст (разом)

- [**Паку́нок**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pakunok).
- Більш вузькі слова:

  - [*блок*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4785&page=180);
  - [*бунт*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=5981&page=220);
  - [*зв'я́зка*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35169&page=1117);
  - [*зго́рток*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35398&page=1122);
  - [*па́ка*](http://sum.in.ua/s/paka);
  - [*па́чка*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pachka);
  - [*стіс* (*стос*)](http://sum.in.ua/s/stis);
  - [*суві́й*](http://sum.in.ua/s/suvij);
  - [*тюк*](http://sum.in.ua/s/tjuk).

## Коли мова йде про саму ємність/обгортку

Тут я не бачу єдиного загального слова, тому наводжу декілька вужчих:

- [**Ємність**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=26592&page=896).
- [**Обго́ртка**](http://sum.in.ua/s/obghortka).
- [**Паке́т**](http://sum.in.ua/s/paket).
- [**По́суд**](http://sum.in.ua/s/posud), [**посу́дина**](http://sum.in.ua/s/posudyna).
- [**Та́ра**](http://sum.in.ua/s/tara).

Answer (score 2):

> Упаковка – (несов.) упаковування, спаковування, пакування, (сов.) упакування, спакування, (материал) **пако́вання**, (бумажный) обгортка.
>   [Згідно з чинними національними термінологічними стандартами технологічний процес потрібно подавати або дієсловом «пакувати» або віддієслівним іменником «пакування», а засіб чи комплекс засобів - віддієслівним іменником «**пакóвання**». Скалькований з російської термін «упаковка» суперечить словотвірним моделям української мови, і тому ним не можна позначати ані процес, ані засіб (М.Гінзбург)].

• [Джерело](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on)