# "ПакУвання" чи "пакОвання"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Як правильно вживати вживати слова "пакування" та "паковання"? Чи є якась різниця між ними? Чи є особливі випадки використання даних слів?

Comment: [Як правильно перекласти “упаковка”](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Розумію, але все ж мене цікавили "паковання" та "пакування", а не "упаковка". Відповідь на своє питання я отримала.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **Пакува́ння** — загальновідоме нормативе слово. Згідно зі «Словником української мови» [позначає дію](http://sum.in.ua/s/pakuvannja). Іноді його використовують і на позначення результату (або використовуваних засобів/матеріалів), але багато хто заперечує правильність такого застосування, наприклад:

  - [Correctarium Blog](//blog.correctarium.com/%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E-6bb8d2c0dfac);
  - [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA/).
- **Пако́вання** — слово, що було присутнє у словниках 1920-х–1930-х років, наприклад:

  - [«Російсько-український словник технічної термінології»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=4&highlight=on) І. Шелудька та Т. Садовського (1928);
  - [«Російсько-український словник ділової мови»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=5&highlight=on) М. Дорошенка, М. Станиславського та В. Страшкевича (1930);
  - [«Російсько-український академічний словник»](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=1&highlight=on) А. Кримського та С. Єфремова (1924–1933).

  Але в новіших радянських словниках не з'являлося; наскільки я можу судити, в сучасних авторитетних словниках воно теж відсутнє. Зате є багато прихильників, щоби повернути його, причому в значенні саме результату пакування чи засобів/матеріалів для пакування, зокрема, наприклад, [М. Гінзбург](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=rusb&dicts=10) і вищезгадані Correctarium Blog, OnlineCorrector.

  Оновлення: А, бачу, що воно з'явилося вже в деяких [словниках](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) і [законах](http://zakon5.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0095-05) (так що рівень визнання цього слова вищий, ніж я думав).